# jQuery object cannot be showed on the page constantly

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to retrieve the items from database and show them in a list dynamically. But every time I get the object back, the item just flashed in a blink and disappeared. I am sure the server works well and returned json object is correctly formatted.

```js
    let amount = 0;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#addItem").click(() => {
                let productID = $("input[name='productID']").val();
                let count = $("input[name='IDQty']").val().toString();

                console.log(productID, count);

                let query = '?';
                if (productID) {
                    query += 'productID=' + productID + "&";
                }
                if (count) {
                    query += 'IDQty=' + count;
                }

                let url = "http://localhost:3000/api/" + query;

                $.getJSON(url, (result) => {
                    console.log(result);
                    $("ul").append("<li>" + result.name + "    " + result.price.toString() + "    " + result.count + "</li>");               
                });
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


         <form>
            ID: <input name="productID">
            Qty: <input name="IDQty" type="number" style="width:60px" value="1" min="1">
           
            <input type="submit" value="Add" id="addItem">
        </form>    
<ul id="receiptContent"></ul>
```

The result showed in console is right and the item did show in the browser for a second. I guess it is a redirect problem, or the way I pass url to `.getJSON` is not right. Any hint? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, you submit the form. Go **return false;** inside the click event, or on form submit event. So, after the `$.getJSON()` or do `$('form').on('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); })`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I never know that submit form also return something except for response data.

Comment: In your case it just reloads the page. You do not need the `<form>` element at all (than you do not need additional script, too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the form tag to

```
<form onsubmit="javascript:return false">
```

Or change the button tag attribute "type" value from "submit" to "button"

Answer (score 0):

Changing form action to JavaScript: void(0) will do the work

```
 <form action="JavaScript: void(0)">
```

Or

```
 <form action="#">
```